# Can a Perl system() call ever die?

Tags: perl, system, eval, die

**Can a `system()` call can ever `die` in Perl 5?**

(in other words, in order to 100% crash-proof a program that does a `system()` call, **does it need to be wrapped into an `eval` block**, or is that wholly totally unnecessary?)

---

I haven't found a single mention to that possibility in [`perldoc system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html), but didn't quite find the precise "this call never dies" either.

NOTE: the question is about basic CORE Perl here, no `autodie` or any other custom module that would have similar effect. Also, assume no `ALRM` signal was set, or any other custom signal handler for that matter.

<sub>I'm assuming that all versions of Perl 5.* behave the same, but if not, an answer pertaining to 5.8 would be appreciated.</sub>

Comment: I haven't gone and looked at the source, so I'm not posting this as an answer, but I'd be surprised if there was no way for `system` to run out of memory.

Comment: @Gilles - would "Out of memory" cause Perl to issue a "die" instead of coredump/crash? I would assume the later, but nor certain

Comment: @Gilles - [if only we had a place where we can ask programming questions...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243637/is-there-a-standard-way-for-perl-to-behave-when-it-runs-out-of-memory). Let's see what the SO wisdom finds out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless my interpretation of the source is incorrect, this looks like a possibility:

Source: Perl 5.16.2 (checked 5.8.8 too), file: pp_sys.c, line: 4224 within the `PP(pp_system)` code block:

```
if (n != sizeof(int))
  DIE(aTHX_ "panic: kid popen errno read, n=%u", n);
```

`DIE` is `Perl_die(pTHX_ const* pat, ...)` declared in `util.c`

According to the documentation, "panic: kid popen errno read" means "forked child returned an incomprehensible message about its errno".

[Explanation of `panic` messages in Perl](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/L3SLVAzhhHs5w7ZUyhl7):

> The convention is that when the interpreter dies with an internal
>   error, the message starts "panic: ". Historically, many panic messages
>   had been terse fixed strings, which means that the out-of-range values
>   that triggered the panic are lost. Now we try to report these values,
>   as such panics may not be repeatable, and the original error message
>   may be the only diagnostic we get when we try to find the cause.

Comment: from my reading of the source this will only happen if 1) the exec() performed by the child fails and 2) the child is unable to send 4 (maybe 8) bytes back to the parent via the pipe.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `system()` with the expectation that it will not throw an exception. There is no need to wrap it in an `eval` block.

Comment: "with the expectation" - is there a technical basis for this? If you look at j.w.r.'s answer, your statement seems totally wrong.

Comment: I would be interested in seeing how many CPAN modules try to catch an exception thrown by `system`. The point is not that it can't happen but rather that you usually can use `system()` with the expectation that it won't throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

`system` returns the exit status of the program. It means, if the program crashes, the calling Perl script continues (see [system](http://p3rl.org/system)).

Nevertheless, the program itself can still kill the calling script or even crash the computer. For example, in Linux:

```
system 'killall', 'perl';
print "Alive\n";
```

Comment: Please see my comment to Brian Agnew. This is not what I was asking about.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're talking about the implementation of the `system` function itself as opposed to whatever is invoked via the call. (Obviously, a child process can't call `die` in the parent's context, and even that assumes that the call is to Perl code.)

A definitive answer would require knowledge of the internals but given that attempting to invoke a non-existent program doesn't die, I can't imagine that anything else ever would, either:

```
system('abcd');      # 'abcd' is not recognized... [Win32 message]
say "I'm not dead."; # always prints
```

Comment: "I assume that you're talking about the implementation of the system function itself as opposed to whatever is invoked via the call." - correct